# SQL - How to join query results in same line

Tags: sql

I have an application that save the working time based on machine, operation, operator and reference.

My query returns the data like this:

```
u_reference | u_user | u_operation | u_machine | price | u_action | Start             | Work time
P-2000-9429 | John   | F3X         | 144       | 60    | PLAY     |2019-11-08 09:40:53| 00:00:00
P-2000-9429 | John   | F3X         | 144       | 60    | PAUSE    |2019-11-08 18:00:45| 08:19:52
P-2000-9429 | John   | F3X         | 144       | 60    | REPLAY   |2019-11-09 07:13:23| 08:19:52
P-2000-9429 | John   | F3X         | 144       | 60    | PAUSE    |2019-11-09 12:19:21| 13:25:49
P-2000-9429 | John   | F3X         | 144       | 60    | REPLAY   |2019-11-11 07:09:50| 13:25:49
P-2000-9429 | John   | F3X         | 144       | 60    | STOP     |2019-11-11 11:03:26| 17:19:21
```

```
select  u_daily_work_alb.u_reference, u_daily_work_alb.u_user, u_daily_work_alb.u_operation, u_machines_alb.u_design as u_machine, u_machines_alb.epcusto as price, u_daily_work_alb.u_action, u_daily_work_alb.u_created_at as Start, u_daily_work_alb.u_work_time as Work_time
from u_daily_work_alb 
  inner join u_machines_alb on u_machines_alb.id = u_daily_work_alb.u_machineId
where u_daily_work_alb.bostamp = 'ALB472248D84210CFA9FE30' 
  and u_daily_work_alb.u_reference = 'p-2000-9429'
order by u_daily_work_alb.id asc
```

bostamp column is like an id.

Now what I need is a result like this:

```
u_reference | u_user | u_operation | u_machine | price | Start             |END                | Work time
P-2000-9429 | John   | F3X         | 144       | 60    |2019-11-08 09:40:53|2019-11-08 18:00:45| calculate time
P-2000-9429 | John   | F3X         | 144       | 60    |2019-11-09 07:13:23|2019-11-09 12:19:21| calculate time
P-2000-9429 | John   | F3X         | 144       | 60    |2019-11-11 07:09:50|2019-11-11 11:03:26| calculate time
```

I think the column `u_action` is important because we know that after a play we have a pause or stop. After a pause we have a replay or stop and after a replay we have a pause or stop.

How can I do that?

Comment: which dbms product are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I have (possibly incorrectly) assumed T-sql. However I think a similar approach could be used in most databases.

I have set up an example below using the tables you provided - you would need to change this to match your underlying query.

basically I get all the start events and assign them a row number based on their event time - i then left join them to all the end events based on that row number.

if it is possible to skip an end event (a start with no pause or stop) - this will cause you problems.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SampleData (
u_reference varchar(100), 
u_user varchar(100), 
u_operation varchar(100), 
u_machine varchar(100), 
price varchar(100), 
u_action varchar(100), 
[Start] datetime, 
[Work time] datetime
)


INSERT INTO dbo.SampleData (u_reference, u_user, u_operation, u_machine, price, u_action, [Start], [Work time])
VALUES  ('P-2000-9429' , 'John'   , 'F3X'         , '144'       , '60'    , 'PLAY'     ,'2019-11-08 09:40:53', '00:00:00'),
        ('P-2000-9429' , 'John'   , 'F3X'         , '144'       , '60'    , 'PAUSE'    ,'2019-11-08 18:00:45', '08:19:52'),
        ('P-2000-9429' , 'John'   , 'F3X'         , '144'       , '60'    , 'REPLAY'   ,'2019-11-09 07:13:23', '08:19:52'),
        ('P-2000-9429' , 'John'   , 'F3X'         , '144'       , '60'    , 'PAUSE'    ,'2019-11-09 12:19:21', '13:25:49'),
        ('P-2000-9429' , 'John'   , 'F3X'         , '144'       , '60'    , 'REPLAY'   ,'2019-11-11 07:09:50', '13:25:49'),
        ('P-2000-9429' , 'John'   , 'F3X'         , '144'       , '60'    , 'STOP'     ,'2019-11-11 11:03:26', '17:19:21')



SELECT  A.u_reference, 
        A.u_user, 
        A.u_operation, 
        A.u_machine, 
        A.price, 
        A.[Start], 
        B.[Start] AS EndTime,
         CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(second, (DATEDIFF(SECOND,A.[Start],B.[Start])), 0), 108) AS WorkingTime

FROM ( 
        -- All Start/Restart Events
        SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Start]) as Rownum
        FROM dbo.SampleData 
        WHERE u_action  IN ('PLAY','REPLAY')

) A 
LEFT JOIN ( 
        -- All End Events
        SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Start]) as Rownum
        FROM dbo.SampleData 
        WHERE u_action  IN ('PAUSE','STOP')

) B
ON A.Rownum = B.Rownum
ORDER BY A.[Start]
```

The Output is;

[image]

Comment: At the question there is no DBMS tag at the moment. Does this query work on any of the DBMS's?

Comment: I did this in t-sql. I think this would also work in oracle.. Not sure about other providers.

Comment: @JamesCooke I detect a problem in this result if I have new lines with different u_operation and u_machine. the endTime is always de first stop and it could have several stops based on u_operation, u_machine and u_reference

Comment: I think i understand the problem - you need to partition by the different machines or operations you want to look at (Its hard for me to know exactly without knowing your data). But I would advice you modify the query provided to ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ***What you want to Partition By*** ORDER BY [Start]) as Rownum

This kind of thing is what I meant with "you will need to change this to match your underlying query"

Comment: So based on what you are saying I would replace ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Start])  With ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u_reference, u_operation, u_machine ORDER BY [Start])

Comment: Ok it resolves the problem, thank you. Now I'm detecting another situation with some records. It is possible has a pause followed by a stop. Play-Pause-Stop and when this happens de EndTime is always wrong. When it happens we have to use the PAUSE and pass the stop record @JamesCooke

Comment: not sure there is a good way around that - the pause is now both a start and end event - i would try and isolate those examples and handle them differently

Comment: I can solve that in the future to hide stop button after a pause but now I have records that I need to show correctly @JamesCooke

Comment: @JamesCooke Do you know another solution to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using lead function if you are using Sql-server.

```
select u_reference, u_user,u_operation,u_machine,price,[Start],[End Time],WorkingTime
from (
SELECT  A.u_reference,A.u_user,A.u_operation,A.u_machine,A.price,A.[Start],A.u_action,lead(Start) over(order by Start) as [End Time],
CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(second, (DATEDIFF(SECOND,[Start],lead(Start) over(order by Start))), 0), 108) AS WorkingTime
from #SampleData A)B where u_action like '%play%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
select u_reference, u_user, u_operation, u_machine,
       start, next_created_at as end,
       <time calculation>  -- this is database dependent
from (select dw.u_reference, dw.u_user, dw.u_operation, 
             m.u_design as u_machine, m.epcusto as price, 
             dw.u_action, dw.u_created_at as Start, 
             dw.u_work_time as Work_time,
             lead(dw.u_created_at) over (partition by dw.u_reference order by dw.u_created_at) as next_created_at,
             lead(dw.u_work_time) over (partition by dw.u_reference order by dw.u_created_at) as next_work_time
      from u_daily_work_alb dw join
           u_machines_alb m
           on m.id = dw.u_machineId
      where dw.bostamp = 'ALB472248D84210CFA9FE30' and 
            dw.u_reference = 'p-2000-9429'
     ) dw
where u_action in ('PLAY', 'REPLAY')
order by dw.id asc;
```

This assumes that the record after a "play"/"replay" provides the information for ending.

Also, it is unclear what keys to use for defining "next".  I don't know if user, operation, and machine (or some combination of them) are needed apart from the reference and time.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff I try use your query but end time is always the next value. For example I can have two plays from same reference with differents operations so it has to detect what is the next pause or stop for that reference, machine and operation

Comment: @user3242861 . . . That is intentional.  That suggests that I did not understand the question correctly.